# Completeness of a theory that is not $\omega$-categorical

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, order-theory, model-theory

Let $T$ be the theory of linear orders with no endpoints and let $\mathcal{L}=\{<,c_0,c_1,\dots\}$ be the language that consists of a binary relation symbol and a countable amount of constant symbols. I want to show that $T_\infty=T\cup\{c_n<c_{n+1}:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is complete. So far, most of the times I've showed that a theory is complete by proving that it's $\omega$-categorical. However, this approach won't work in this particular example. Apparently, this has been asked before in MSE, but the suggested arguments involve Ehrenfeucht-Fraïssé games, which I'm not familiar with.

Is there another way to show this? If not, can you explain how could I use EF games to solve this problem?

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To show $T$ is complete, we need to show that for every sentence $\varphi$, $T\models \varphi$ or $T\models\lnot\varphi$.

Observation: The sentence $\varphi$ only uses finitely many symbols, so it is is an $\mathcal{L}'$-sentence for some finite sublanguage $\mathcal{L'}\subseteq \mathcal{L}$.

Can you show that the restriction of $T$ to $\mathcal{L}'$-sentences is complete?

Comment: Thanks for your help Alex! So basically, if $c_{i_1},\dots c_{i_k}$ are the only constants in $\varphi$, then I can consider it as an $\mathcal{L}'$-sentence, where $\mathcal{L}'=\{<, c_0,\dots c_N\}$, where $N=\max\{i_j:1\leq j\leq k\}$. The restriction $T'$ of $T$ to $\mathcal{L}'$-sentences is actually $\omega$-categorical, so it is complete. Will that work?

Comment: @closedrhombus you got it!